# Error even after installing Xlrd in Python 3.6

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have installed Pip of Xlrd and I am seeing success

```
C:\Users\<FilePath>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip.exe install C:\Users\<FilePath>\Downloads\xlrd-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd==1.1.0 from file:///C:/Users/<FilePath>/Downloads/xlrd-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl in c:\users\<FilePath>\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (1.1.0)

C:\Users\<FilePath>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip3.6.exe install C:\Users\<FilePath>\Downloads\xlrd-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd==1.1.0 from file:///C:/Users/<FilePath>/Downloads/xlrd-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl in c:\users\<FilePath>\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (1.1.0)
```

Now in python code , i am writing as

```
import xlrd
```

Below error is seen :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/<FilePath>", line 2, in <module>
    import xlrd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

I think, i am doing simple mistake and tried to find out allot but I am not successful . Please help me

Comment: what is `<FilePath>`?  (does it end with xlrd.py?

Comment: It seems the python you used to run pip and install `xlrd` is not the same python you're using to run the code. You can have multiple python installations in the same machine, and that can be confusing.

Comment: @thebjorn if your asking abt error , no it will end with  test.py

Comment: @nosklo no I have only one python in my machine

Comment: How do you run your python code?

Comment: @thebjorn I m using Pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default PyCharm creates a new virtualenv for each project. The easiest way to add a new dependency is to go to settings -> Project -> Project interpreter and add it from there:

[image: PyCharm add package dialog]